# Adonisjs filtrar as tabelas no .preload

Tags: node.js, adonisjs

sou novo com o adonisjs , no meu controller tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
export default class StudentsController {
public async show({ params }: HttpContextContract) {
    const student = await Student.query().preload('rooms').where('id', params.id)

    return student
  }
}
```

um exemplo do retorno no insomnia:

```
{
        "id": 1001,
        "name": "Leonardo",
        "email": "rafael@teste.com",
        "birthdate": "04/01/1995",
        "rooms": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "teacher_id": 5001,
                "capacity": 4,
                "available": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

- até aqui tudo ok, está retornando o preload('rooms)
- **oque eu preciso é que o .preload "rooms" retorne somente o "id" e o
  "teacher_id"**

Answer (score 0):

Para buscar apenas algumas das colunas presentes na tabela é necessário informa-las através do SELECT conforme as documentações a seguir:
https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/database/query-builder#select-queries
https://legacy.adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/query-builder#_selects

Segue um exemplo de código de como ficaria no seu caso:

```
export default class StudentsController {
public async show({ params }: HttpContextContract) {
    const student = await Student.query().preload('rooms').select('id', 'teacher_id').where('id', params.id)
    return student
  }
}
```